# Regexp ignores some letters

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to solve [Chasing Subs problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/chasingsubs). I'm trying to generate that regex according to the input data. The goal is go get all substrings (including overlapped ones) with all unique letters.

I'm trying to use regexp like this:

```
regexp = /(?=(?<gs>.)(?<gu>[^\k<gs>])(?<gb>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>])(?<gm>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>])(?<ga>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>\k<gm>])(?<gr>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>\k<gm>\k<ga>])(?<gi>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>\k<gm>\k<ga>\k<gr>])(?<gn>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>\k<gm>\k<ga>\k<gr>\k<gi>])(?<ge>[^\k<gs>\k<gu>\k<gb>\k<gm>\k<ga>\k<gr>\k<gi>\k<gn>]))/
"archipelago".scan(regexp) #=> []
"archipelbgo".scan(regexp) #=> []
"brchipelbgo".scan(regexp) #=> []
"zrchipelzgo".scan(regexp) #=> [["z", "r", "c", "h", "i", "p", "e", "l", "z"]]
```

Why does it behave like this? Why can't it find anything with `"b"` and `"a"`? And why does it return only one (incorrect) result with `"z"`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inside a negated character class, almost all special chars lose their special meaning. `[^\k<gs>]` should be written as `(?!\k<gs>).`

Comment: *"with all unique letters"* -- not quite a job for `regex`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you move your comment to answer? It worked.

Comment: I never received feedback on my answer. Is it was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a regular expression is the correct tool for this problem. We could do the following, however.

```
def substrings(str)
  arr = str.chars
  (1..str.size).each_with_object([]) { |n,a|
    arr.each_cons(n) { |b| a << b.join if b == b.uniq } }
end

substrings("archipelago")
  #=> ["a", "r", "c", "h", "i", "p", "e", "l", "a", "g", "o", "ar", "rc", "ch", "hi",
  #    "ip", "pe", "el", "la", "ag", "go", "arc", "rch", "chi", "hip", "ipe", "pel",
  #    "ela", "lag", "ago", "arch", "rchi", "chip", "hipe", "ipel", "pela", "elag",
  #    "lago", "archi", "rchip", "chipe", "hipel", "ipela", "pelag", "elago", "archip",
  #    "rchipe", "chipel", "hipela", "ipelag", "pelago", "archipe", "rchipel", "chipela",
  #    "hipelag", "ipelago", "archipel", "rchipela", "chipelag", "hipelago", "rchipelag",
  #    "chipelago", "rchipelago"]
```